# Why can't I build a swc in my Flex Builder Project after pasting a class?

Tags: flash-builder, swc

This may be a bug report for Adobe, but thought I'd ask here for workarounds...

When I create a new Flex Library Project, a .swc is automatically created in the /bin folder.  When I add a new class, the .swc is updated (I can tell by looking at the 'last modified' timestamp of the .swc).  When I edit that class, the .swc is also updated.  This is all as expected, since Project > Build Automatically is checked.

However, as soon as I paste in other classes, I can no longer update the .swc.
The datestamp does not change, no matter what edits I perform.
Unchecking and re-checking Project>Build Automatically does nothing.
Even worse, Project>Clean deletes the .swc file, and I cannot recreate it!

Is there any way to force Flex Builder to build a .swc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The classes I pasted into the Library Project had dependencies on other classes that were not present in the project.  This caused build errors.  Those build errors caused the .swc compile to fail silently.

I didn't notice the build errors in the Problems pane, and Flash Builder didn't notify me that the compilation failed, so I was floundering around looking for answers in the wrong places.

More here:
http://words.transmote.com/wp/20120511/flex-library-project-build-errors/